# Can cache manifest files be served from a different host?

Tags: html, offlineapps, manifest.cache

I am hosting a cache manifest file for a friend, because his server serves manifest files as plain text and he can't change it. He's hosting the rest of his pages himself, on his server. So his `<html>` tag has a `manifest` attribute that is a complete URL that points to my server.

But it doesn't seem to be working. Is this because the cache manifest file is from a different host as the web page that it is in?

Comment: He could use PHP to serve up the `cache.manifest` with the correct MIME type. Ex set `manifest="manifest.php"` then in `manifest.php` you only need two lines:

    `header('Content-Type: text/cache-manifest');
    readfile('cache.manifest');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The manifest attribute can point to an absolute URL or relative path, but an absolute URL must be under the same origin as the web application

[Source](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/appcache/beginner/#toc-manifest-file-creating).